# Save/Write encrypted Bytes from Cipher to a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, encryption, bufferedwriter

I am currently trying to encrypt and decrypt a String with Cipher. The problem i ran into is that I am trying to save the encrypted bytes to a file and after that decrypt them again. I am currently trying to do this with `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`. The problem is I dont get the same Byte array I saved. Any recommendations on how to write/read the bytes in a working way? I would already be happy if you could post a tutorial which includes saving the encrypted bytes to a file (and loading it again)

Comment: If you want help with your code it is generally expected that post the relevant portions of it.

Comment: As I already know my Code is completely wrong, I asked which alternatives there are for bufferedreader and writer which are more Cipher friendly. My Code wouldnt be of any use here.

Comment: @Slashking even if it is wrong it would show that you have made some efforts solving your prob

Comment: readers and writers are for characters. The result of an encryption process is bytes, not characters. Use a FileInput/OutputStream.

Comment: How do I get the InputStream to returning a byte array with the read() method instead of a int?

Comment: It works finally! Thanks JB Nizet!

Comment: When working with encryption it's important to understand that virtually all encryption algorithms produce a string of "pure binary" output bytes that are gibberish if displayed as characters.  Further, whenever you try to treat them as characters the system "translates" them based on some presumed "code page", and that translation is damaging to the encrypted bytes.  So (unless you know what you're doing), encrypted bytes should never be placed in a character string, written to a "character" file, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I am currently trying to do this with BufferedReader and BufferedWriter.

Why? That's the problem right there. These classes are for character data. Use streams.